# Opening specific view with navigation controller from push notication

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Im trying to open a certain view from a push notification but i keep losing the nav bar and the back and next references. this what my storyboard looks like this (with the view i want to open)

[image]

this is what i have in my AppDelagate:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notification") as? NotificationViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
```

Comment: you should embed it in a navigation controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is completely replacing the root view controller of your application, this means that all the current UI will be discarded.

What you should do instead is to use your knowledge of your application to direct it to the new content. For example, if your root view controller is a navigation controller, you can cast `rootViewController` to a nav controller and push it (this will fail if your root view controller is something else, like a tab bar controller).

```
guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notification") as? NotificationViewController else {
  fatalError("Main Storyboard doesn't have a notification controller")
}
guard let nav = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else {
  return //handle unexpected state
}
nav.push(vc, animated: true)
```

Another option would be to embed your notification controller into a navigation controller, add a `Close` button, and present it modally, that way you can present it on top of `rootViewController` no matter what that controller is.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see in the screenshot your provided, the application's root view controller is the `UINavigationController` instance.

And according to that, let me offer the next code:

```
func handleNotification(){
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notification") as? NotificationViewController else{
            debugPrint("NotificationViewController with identifier 'notification' not found")
            return
        }

        guard let navVC = self.window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController else{
            debugPrint("RootViewController is not an UINavigationController")
            return
        }

        navVC.pushViewController(vc, animated: true) //perhaps your will prefer to use false
    }
```

Beside that, you can use more flexible implementation.

In your AppDelegate post a (NS)Notification when notification intercepted, the relevant view-controller(s) observe the notification, and act when notification broadcasted.

You can also set an identifier to the segue and invoke `performSegue` method from the observing view-controller

Answer (score 0):

You can set from storyboard -> add view controller -> Embed in navigation controller -> set second view controller -> Attach seque between that controllers. You will see same view controllers like that image .

Comment: this gives me a new navigation controller, which i cant use the back button to return to the previous view.

Comment: You can hide it left bar button